# Error when deploying WAR file

Tags: deployment, war, web-deployment

I have a war file and when deploying it thro the admin console in websphere i am getting the following error after specifying the war file location and the context-root.

> The EAR file might be corrupt or incomplete.
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml

Any suggesstions to resolve this issue?

I also unpacked the war file and checked that the web.xml file is present in the web-inf folder.

Cheers,
Deena

Comment: How did you create the EAR file?

Comment: There seem to be other people with the same problem. Something about the element order in <web-app/>: http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=35465

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after much searching (and even posting a bounty for this problem), I found the issue was comments in web.xml.

I was lucky enough to have a source branch that didn't have the comments and worked and this other branch that did have the comments and broke.

Removing the comments allowed WebSphere's validator to get past that error... fun stuff..

Comment: Looks like the WebSphere guys already know about it and have made patches for it. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM49316